# How to get documentElement.innerHTML on my "dynamic" table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm new with Javascript and I try to get the source code of my current page, with values, in a variable.

As you can see, in "myTable2", the script works and we get the different values in each 's..
But my problem is that I can't get "myTable1"... She simply don't appear in the window.alert.

To get rows on myTable1, I have a function ("addligne") who just takes values of table2 to table1.

Thanks in advance !

HTML :

```
<div id="liste_ingredient">

        <table id="myTable1">
            <tr>
                <th>Nom ingredient</th>
                <th>Code ingredient</th>
                <th>Statut ingredient</th>
                <th>Symbole ingredient</th>
                <th>Suppression</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>

</div>
</br></br></br>
<div>

        <table id="myTable2">
            <tr>
                <th>Nom ingredient</th>
                <th>Code ingredient</th>
                <th>Statut ingredient</th>
                <th>Symbole ingredient</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input id="nom_ingredient" type="text" name="nom_ingredient" placeholder="Nom de l'ingrédient"/></td>
                <td><input id="code_ingredient" type="text" name="code_ingredient" placeholder="Code de l'ingrédient"/></td>
                <td><input id="statut_ingredient" type="text" name="statut_ingredient" placeholder="Statut de l'ingrédient"/></td>
                <td><input id="symbole_ingredient" type="text" name="symbole_ingredient" placeholder="Symbole de l'ingrédient"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

<button id="addligne">Add</button>
<button id="getHTML">getHTML!</button>
```

JS :

```
$('#getHTML').click(function() {
    alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML); 
});

$('input').change(function() {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());            
});

$('#addligne').click(function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable1").tBodies[0];
    var nom_ingredient = document.getElementById("nom_ingredient").value;
    var code_ingredient = document.getElementById("code_ingredient").value;
    var statut_ingredient = document.getElementById("statut_ingredient").value;
    var symbole_ingredient = document.getElementById("symbole_ingredient").value;
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="nom_ingredient" value="'+ nom_ingredient +'"/>';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="code_ingredient" value="'+ code_ingredient +'"/>';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="statut_ingredient" value="'+ statut_ingredient +'"/>';
    cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="symbole_ingredient" value="'+ symbole_ingredient +'"/>';
    cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Supprimer" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';

    document.getElementById("nom_ingredient").value = "";
    document.getElementById("code_ingredient").value = "";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/td8o348L/

PS : I put the minimum on this jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
   alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

To this:

```
   alert($('html').html());
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/td8o348L/1/  (I used console.log so it's easier to read through)

Comment: myTable1 is still empty (after I added some rows of course) http://i.imgur.com/0QdnKPJ.jpg

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what you are asking then? I clearly see the added row(s) in the source I am outputting to the console: http://eskimospy.com/img/daily/rows.png  That is what you are after, yes?

Comment: Oh you were right, it worked ! Thanks a lot you just saved my life ♥